# What does it mean OutOfcpu error in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I got OutOfcpu in kubernetes on googlecloud what does it mean? My pods seem to be working now, however there there were pods in this same revision which got OutOfcpu.

Comment: Does your worker nodes runs out of CPU resources to schedule pods?

Comment: @sacherus better if you replace the above image by the text it contains.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the image and added some explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler) can't find any node with available CPU to schedule your pods:

> kube-scheduler selects a node for the pod in a 2-step operation:
>
> 1. Filtering
> 2. Scoring
>
> The *filtering* step finds the set of Nodes where it’s feasible to
>   schedule the Pod. For example, the `PodFitsResources` filter checks
>   whether a candidate Node has enough available resource to meet a Pod’s
>   specific resource requests.
>   [...]
>   `PodFitsResources`: Checks if the
>   Node has free resources (eg, CPU and Memory) to meet the requirement
>   of the Pod.

Also, as per [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/):

> If the named node does not have the resources to accommodate the pod,
>   the pod will fail and its reason will indicate why, e.g. OutOfmemory
>   or **OutOfcpu**.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [how-kube-scheduler-schedules-pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler-implementation), I think this will be helpful to understand why `OutOfcpu` error has been shown up.

> When you create a Pod, the Kubernetes scheduler selects a node for the
>   Pod to run on. Each node has a maximum capacity for each of the
>   resource types: the amount of CPU and memory it can provide for Pods.
>   The scheduler ensures that, for each resource type, the sum of the
>   resource requests of the scheduled Containers is less than the
>   capacity of the node. Note that although actual memory or CPU resource
>   usage on nodes is very low, the scheduler still refuses to place a Pod
>   on a node if the capacity check fails. This protects against a
>   resource shortage on a node when resource usage later increases, for
>   example, during a daily peak in request rate.

Ref: [how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled)